# How can I open this external app from Electron securely?

Tags: node.js, shell, security, electron

I'm prototyping an Electron app that can open provided files in a third party photo editor, using Node's `childProcess` API:

```
const process = childProcess.spawn(
    'open', 
    ['-a', 'Polarr Photo Editor', filename],
    {shell: false}
);
```

I'm a little concerned about the security of passing in an unsanitised `filename` as a parameter. For context, here's how the app might work:

1. It requests a JSON payload from our server, which lists a set of assets in S3
2. Those assets are downloaded locally
3. The user can then choose which one to open in his or her editor
4. After making edits, they can re-upload to us

My concern is that a MITM attack around stage 1 could mean a user downloads a maliciously named file, a filename that can do *evil things* when passed as a parameter to `spawn`, e.g. `myCoolFile && doEvilThing ;.jpg`.

I have done a little testing, and haven't found any obvious exploits *yet*, but I'm worried I might be missing something.

Therefore I'd like to know:

1. Can parameters sent to `spawn` hijack the command, produce evil side effects - do anything unexpected or undesirable in the hands of a malicious user?
2. If so, what can I do? Are there better alternatives to opening third party applications from a Node process?
3. Is there any general good practice for security in Electron apps that I should be reading up on?

Comment: This code runs in client side (i mean in the electron app), not in your server side right?

Comment: That's right, in the Electron desktop app.

Comment: I suppose you can check it with https://www.npmjs.com/package/valid-filename and check that it has supported extension.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see this as a security issue. There is two reasons

First one is the filename is only a parameter that is send to a third party application. So that executable should validate the parameter to check weather it is a file or not. If it doesn't it is out of your scope and you may have to ask them to fix that or alternatively validate it is a filename.

And the second reason is this happens in the client side, So the user will be responsible for passing the filename, even if it's done manually. You have no control over what he might execute on his own system and that is okay. Even though you made it impossible.

You user can always execute `open -a Polarr Photo Editor anything_he_want` on his terminal if he want to crack it.